# Eclipse - Console didn't show the Python code fragment output

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I wrote a simple code fragment using Eclipse version 3.7. After I run the file as a Python project. The console didn't show the simple output.

- I installed Python plug-in version 2.7.5 onto Eclipse
- I downloaded the Python 3.3.2 package onto my laptop computer, configured
  it and add PATH variable to the environment path setting.

My simple code fragment

```
print "Hello World!"  # or print("Hello World!")
```

I am expected to see the phase `"Hello World!"` on the Console screen in Eclipse, but it is not shown as run the code fragment in Python Shell.

[image]

[image]

Please give me some advises on what steps I need to take in order to see the output in Eclipse.

Comment: BTW, `print "Hello World!"` is invalid syntax for Python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save your file with the `.py` extension (i.e. `exercise1.py`), denoting it as a Python source file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. By right clicking on the file name>Rename the file as exercise1.py>Run As Python Run did the trick. I can see the output __Hello World_ in the console screen in Eclipse.